# React-Native API Module C++

Tags: c++, api, reactjs, react-native, module

I would like to create a bridge with a module C++ for react-native
On the documentation of React native we have a tutorial for Swift and Objective-C but don't with C++
Someone know how we do that ?
Link React-native Module : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Comment: Might be useful: https://github.com/dropbox/djinni